# icons missing from libreoffice toolbars

Tags: libreoffice

New Ubuntu 16.04.2 installation.  **Uninstalled** the default `libreoffice` installation. Then I installed libreoffice 5.4.0.3 from this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

Now all icons are missing from toolbars:

[image: libreoffice calc toolbar]

*Is this a bug or a funk setting?* Any thoughts on how to reset the toolbar to get the typical configuration? I already tried the basic stuff (rebooting, disable/enable toolbars, etc.)

Comment: Just adding the PPA and update/upgrade would be sufficient. No need to unistall and I'm afraid you may have uninstalled something you shouldn't. And no, I don't know how to solve it and it may well be off topic.

Comment: Although your advice might be accurate, I've always uninstalled first and have never seen this behavior. Could just be a bum install. Thank you for reply.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Libreoffice was upgraded to version 5.4.0.3 through the "software update" process automatically in first week of August.

Comment: with me this is due to the custom dark mode and libre-office trying to be clever adding light icons on light  background ...

Answer (score 39):

Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View

Switch **Icon style** from Automatic to another style in dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I solved this in this way

1) install other style: in my case  `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-human`

2) change the style configuration: Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View

In my case I've updated with this ppa too, and broke in the same way. I suppose that I have one incompatibility with the Libreoffice-style-mint or something like this.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-style-galaxy
```

will do. You could also install other libreoffice-style-* packages.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, the solution was installing breeze icon theme.

```
apt install libreoffice-style-breeze
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View

The problem is selecting large icon size.
Change it auto. My icons came back.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  I do not see any difference between your answer and the first one.  In such a case, it is better to upvote the answer than to add another one.  This increases the visibility of the selected answer without addind clutter in the site.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen this is the only answer that mentions icon size though. I think you didn't read closely enough